# Drag and drop without new UI system

Tags: unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I have several gameobjects which I'm dragging around. All of them instantiate from prefab with `Collider2D` on them.

My goal is that when I move/drag any of these objects over a specified zone (another `GameObject` with `Collider2D` on it), the dragged object should visually change. Then, when I drop it, it should do something different based on where I dropped it (inside or outside this zone).

I thought in several directions, but none of them give me what I want.

1. `OnCollider2d` won't work because there is no RigidBody.
2. `OnMouseEnter` on zone object blocked by object I'm dragging.
3. `blocksRaycasts` of CanvasGroup component didn't work for non-Canvas objects.

Comment: use nGUI it is suitable for GUI

Comment: if the zone is just rectangle/square area, could manually check if object is inside that area.. Other option: Raycast on mouse position to see if it hits the zone object (can use layermask to cast ray on specific layer only)

Comment: for this particular case i don't wanna use UI or any 3rd-party stuff. it looks like is could be done without any of it with some simple stuff but i just don't know how. is rayscasting to specific layer won't be blocked by object i currently dragging?